# flutter Force listview builder to show only 1 item based on condition

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-hive

I am making a to-do project using hive and I want to show the todos that are marked as completed and not completed in a different row. Now when the mark as completed row is empty I want to show a message like "You can mark todos as completed after completing the todo". I have implemented these features but the problem is the message "You can mark todos as completed after completing the todo" repeats with the number of items in the todo. for example if the todo contains 2 todos and both are not completed then I get the message:

"You can mark todos as completed after completing the todo"
"You can mark todos as completed after completing the todo"

Code I am working with:

```
ListView.builder(
                  primary: false,
                  itemCount: Hive.box___.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Todo? data = Hive.box____.getAt(index);
                    return data!.isCompleted
                        ? _______ //show the todos that are completed
                        : const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "You can mark todos as completed after completing the todo"
                            ),
                          );
                  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to also put a condition on itemCount.

so you have 2 listviews. one for not completed and one for completed items.

in each `ListView`, you have to filter your list so filtered items are passed to each list. in the completed list view you write

```
itemCount: completedItems.lenth == 0 ? 1 : completedItems.lenth
```

and in builder, you have to check if `completedItems.lenth` is zero then return `Text` else return the corresponding card.

Comment: how to access completed item before item builder or outside of listview

Comment: you have to filter your list. somethin like: todoList.filter((element) => element.isCompleted)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue, first I have filtered and checked if there are no completed items if it is so, I have shown item count as 1 else it will be the length of the to-do list.

here is my code

```
ListView.builder(
                  primary: false,
                  itemCount: Hive.box___.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Todo? data = Hive.box__.values
                          .where((element) => element.iscompleted == true)
                          .isEmpty
                      ? 1
                      : Hive.box____.length,;
                    return data!.isCompleted
                        ? _______ //show the todos that are completed
                        : const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "You can mark todos as completed after completing the todo"
                            ),
                          );
                  },
```

Also, my code is inspired by the one shared by @Riza and thanks for letting me know about `Hive.box____.get('name')` @Giorgi

Answer (score 0):

implement data outside builder

```
 List<Todo>? data = Hive.box____.get('name')
 int count = Hive.box___.length;
        ListView.builder(
                          primary: false,
                          itemCount:count,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                           );
                            if(data![index].isCompleted){
                                return _______ //show the todos that are completed
}
                                else {return const Center(
                                   child: Text(
                                      "You can mark todos as completed after completing the todo"
                                    ),
                                  );
count = 0;
}
                          },
```

Comment: how to get the index outside of the item builder?

Comment: you don't need index outside of the item builder. updated

Comment: I have checked and confirmed it is the same, Hive.box___.length is 2 even there are no completed items It runs twice

Comment: try this i edit code

Comment: you just need to stop builder after enter else